# Run a thread in a core with lowest priority

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

In c++ how can I run a thread always in a core with lowest priority. We can use **sched_getcpu()** for assign a core specific to a thread, but how can we implement the low priority running?

Comment: That function returns the number of the CPU the thread is running on. It does not set it. OS decides where your code runs.

Comment: Am I missing something but on a Symmetric Multiprocessor (SMP) environment all cores are equal and run in parallel so there is no concept of prioritization even though what ultimately gets run on each core needs to be prioritized by the os?

Comment: You have no control over that.  Your operating system process scheduler is handling this.  On Linux however you can adjust the scheduler's parameters: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/linuxonibm/liaai.saptuning/saptuningadjust.htm

Comment: In my application I have a background process(thread), that must run always in a single core and if there any high priority thread coming then it must wait.

Comment: @ArunKS you can just assing low priority to your thread, [yield](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) your thread, however consider these options only as *hints* to the system's scheduler

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with `std::thread`, yet you can obtain the [native_handle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) and set [core affinity](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) and [priority](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) (look at the example) with the pthread handle.

EDIT: This is for Linux, on Windows you would get a different handle.